# Getting clock schedule to start in python kivy app

Tags: python, kivy, clock

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I've tried several variations, and I can't get Clock to schedule the function12. Please help. Thank you!

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG"] = "1"
from kivy.app import App
import time
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainApp(App):

    def on_start(self):
        print("Here")
        Clock.schedule_once(self.function12,5)
        print("Here")
        time.sleep(100)

    def function12(self):
        print("INSIDE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `function12()` method needs a `dt` argument, like this:

```
def function12(self, dt):
    print("INSIDE")
```

And the scheduled method cannot run until the `time.sleep()` has completed, since the `on_start()` method is running on the main thread, and the `sleep` holds the main thread.